# Java JDBC program throwing SQL syntax error when fetching particular rows from a table

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, xampp

I have a database called 'airplane' inside which there is a table named timetable . The timeatable table has a column fromcity of text type

```
                    Connection conn0=null;
                    PreparedStatement st0=null;
                    String sql0="SELECT FROM timetable where fromcity=?";

                try{
                        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                        conn0=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
                        st0=conn0.prepareStatement(sql0);
                        st0.setString(1,city[i]);
                        ResultSet rs0=st0.executeQuery();

                        if(rs0.next())
                        {
                            System.out.println("flight exists");
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("fight does not exist");
                        }


                    }
                    catch(Exception et)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Error"+et.getMessage());
                    }
```

I am getting the error:

why am I getting this error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM timetable where fromcity='1'' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to write column names in your query.

Make it,

```
SELECT * FROM timetable where fromcity=?"
```

instead of,

```
SELECT FROM timetable where fromcity=?"
```